# Reading the "sensitive" results of AWS SageMaker InvokeEndpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to invoke a sagemaker serverless endpoint using the Go SDK and the result is not returned, it's marked as "sensitive". From the [docs](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/ae7f3e0d9f392eaf4c3f7c7fb1cef3391ef8abfd/service/sagemakerruntime/api.go#L773) it says that the body will not be returned but it doesn't say how to retrieve it.

```golang
svc := sagemakerruntime.New(sess)
out, err := svc.InvokeEndpoint(&sagemakerruntime.InvokeEndpointInput{
    Body:         []byte(`xxx`),
    ContentType:  aws.String("application/json"),
    EndpointName: aws.String("xxx"),
})
```

Result:

```json
{
  Body: <sensitive>,
  ContentType: "application/json",
  InvokedProductionVariant: "single-variant"
}
```

When I invoke it using the aws-cli, it populates the output file correctly with the result json.

```
aws sagemaker-runtime invoke-endpoint --content-type 'application/json' --endpoint-name xxx --body xxx /tmp/sagemaker-output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Body is a sensitive parameter and its value will be replaced with "sensitive" in string returned by InvokeEndpointOutput's String and GoString methods.

As stated in the document, it only affects the string returned by the `String` and `GoString` methods. You still can access the `Body` field directly.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/sagemakerruntime"
)

func main() {
    output := &sagemakerruntime.InvokeEndpointOutput{
        Body:                     []byte("body data"),
        ContentType:              aws.String("application/json"),
        InvokedProductionVariant: aws.String("single-variant"),
    }

    fmt.Println(output)
    fmt.Printf("body: %s\n", output.Body)
}
```

Output:

```
{
  Body: <sensitive>,
  ContentType: "application/json",
  InvokedProductionVariant: "single-variant"
}
body: body data
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea on the reasoning behind hiding it in the general output.String()?

Comment: It's a common requirement to hide sensitive data when writing to the log. It helps when a careless user log the output directly.